# Nexus 7 , Android Ver. 4.2.2, Locking icons down on home screen

Tags: home-screen

We have a set of 30 Nexus 7's that are checked out by students who constantly delete/move/add icons on the home screen.  We would like to lock the home screen icons so that they cannot be deleted/moved or added to.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not without changing the launcher, I suspect.

Answer (score 4):

Have a play with [SureLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock&hl=en) in the Play store. It is pretty good at locking the home screen down.