# Application to block icon movements on home pages

Tags: applications

Is there an application that doesn't allow me to move icons on the home page when I long press them in order to prevent accidental movements?

So for instance if I long press the Camera icon on the main screen I'd like nothing to happen while this application I'm asking about is active/installed.

LE: Of course I search the Play store and haven't found such an app.

Comment: [Nexus 7 , Android Ver. 4.2.2, Locking icons down on home screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43966/981), [Can I prevent home screen shortcuts from getting deleted or moved around?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38297/981)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It highly depends on what device you have, because of different ROM and launcher variations. You may download a different (3rd party) launcher from the Play Store and easly lock its layout: GO Launcher and ADW support this. I don't know, maybe Nova also.